# Mapping table children content with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

My goal is to fetch `.textContent` from different `<td>` tags, each lying within a separate `<tr>`.

I think the problem lies within the `table` variable, as I am not checking the correct variable for children. Currently, `data` variable is only fetching the first `<tr>`, so `price` evaluates with this code. However, `volume` and `turnover` does not. I think it is a simple fix but I just can't figure it out!

JavaScript:

```
try {
    const tradingData = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let table = document.querySelector("#trading-data tbody");
      let tableData = Array.from(table.children);
      let data = tableData.map(tradeData => {
        console.log(tradeData);
        let price = tradeData.querySelector(".quoteapi-price").textContent;
        console.log(price);
        let volume = tradeData.querySelector("quoteapi-volume").textContent;
        console.log(volume);
        let turnover = tradeData.querySelector("quoteapi-value").textContent;
        console.log(turnover);
        return { price, volume, turnover };
      })
      return data;
    });

    console.log(tradingData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

HTML:

```html
<table id="trading-data" class="qq_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="qq_tr_border_bot">
            <td>Price</td>
            <td class="qq_td_right quoteapi-number quoteapi-price" data-quoteapi="price">$0.105</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="qq_tr_border_bot">
            <td>Change</td>
            <td class="qq_td_right pos" data-quoteapi="changeSignCSS">
                <span data-quoteapi="change (signed)" class="quoteapi-number quoteapi-price quoteapi-change">0.005</span>
                <span data-quoteapi="pctChange (pct)" class="quoteapi-number quoteapi-pct-change">(5.00%)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="qq_tr_border_bot">
            <td>Volume</td>
            <td class="qq_td_right quoteapi-number quoteapi-volume" data-quoteapi="volume scale=false">5,119,162</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Turnover</td>
            <td class="qq_td_right quoteapi-number quoteapi-value" data-quoteapi="value scale=false">$540,173</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For example, this should return `price="$0.11"`, `volume="3,900,558"`, `turnover="$412,187"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the `map` function when you are expecting multiple tables or tbodies. As this seems not to be the case in your example, you can do it like this:

```js
const tradingData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let table = document.querySelector("#trading-data tbody");
    let price = table.querySelector(".quoteapi-price").textContent;
    let volume = table.querySelector(".quoteapi-volume").textContent;
    let turnover = table.querySelector(".quoteapi-value").textContent;
    return { price, volume, turnover };
});
console.log(tradingData);
```